# the unity names space Rendering won't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

using unity to make a game and trying to use the Unity.Rendering but it wont work, it is just grayed out and it says "using directive unnecessary" also the systems are saying the same.

if i load it up in visual on its own it works fine.

any ideas?

```
using System.Collections; //says using directive unnecessary
using System.Collections.Generic; //says using directive unnecessary
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Transforms;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using Unity.Rendering; //says using directive unnecessary
'
    public class ECSBulletSpawn : MonoBehaviour
    {
        EntityManager entityManager;
        public int Count { get; set; } = 0;
        public GameObject micheal;
    
        [SerializeField] private Mesh bulletMesh;
        [SerializeField] private Material bulletMaterial;
        Entity bulletPrototype;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            
            entityManager = World.DefaultGameObjectInjectionWorld.EntityManager;
            var desc = new RenderMeshDescription( // THIS IS NOT WORKING
                bulletMesh,
                bulletMaterial);
    
            Entity entity = entityManager.CreateEntity(typeof(Prefab)); 
            RenderMeshUtility.AddComponents(  // THIS IS NOT WORKING
                entity,
                entityManager,
                desc);
        }'
```

Comment: [Remove unnecessary using directives (IDE0005)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0005)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the classes that you are having trouble with, but you should make sure that they are defined in `Unity.Rendering` and not in `UnityEditor.Rendering` or `UnityEngine.Rendering`